# Differences between variable type declarations?

Tags: swift, variables

Is there any difference between:

```
var a:Int
```

and:

```
var a = Int()
```

To me they look pretty much the same, but is there an obvious difference that should be known when staring out with programming?

Comment: The first declares a variable `a` as type `Int`, but it does not initialize it.  If you tried to `print(a)` after that, you'd get an error. The second creates `a` of type `Int` and initializes it to `0`.  No one declares an `Int` this way, but it is common for more complex structures and classes.  You usually would do that like this instead `var a = 0` and Swift will infer the type to be `Int`.

Comment: i suggest that you always initialize your variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the difference:

In the first one:

```
var a: Int
```

You're declaring a variable of type **Int** but there is no actual value assigned to it yet.

Whereas, in the second one:

```
var a = Int()
```

You're declaring variable **a** where you don't explicitly give it a type, but since you're setting it to Int() which is number zero, compiler can guess the type. So from the assigned value, compiler will infer the type.

To conclude, in the first one, there is no value assigned but in the second one, value of **a** is zero.